# How to pass two variables to a folder name in a for-loop

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, variables

I want to copy folder M0R0 to M1R0, M1R1, M1R2, etc.

```
echo -n "M= "
read m
echo -n "From run= "
read r1
echo -n "To run= "
read r2

for i in $(seq $r1 $r2)
do
        echo "M$mR$i"
        cp -rp M0R0 M$mR$i
done
```

However this code ignores the second variable $i and it only creates directory M1

Comment: The problem should be with the `$m` variable. You're trying to use `$mR` instead.

Comment: When you want to loop after both `Mx` and `Rx`, you should have a second loop inside the first one. `for ((m=0;m,10;m++)); do for i=0;i<5;i++)); do ..done;done`

Comment: The answer you are referring to is good for the one who already know the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really  don't need to use sequences. Also, when using substitution use `${}` to indicate where the variable to be substituted.

```
echo -n "M= "
read m
echo -n "From run= "
read r1
echo -n "To run= "
read r2

for ((i=$r1; i <=$r2; ++i));
do
        echo "M${m}R${i}"
        cp -rp M0R0 "M${m}R${i}"
done
```